# Verify emails using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email-validation

How can I verify when a visitor registers on my website, that the email he/she has used is valid. I would like to email them a link which they can click to prove their membership, how can this be done?

Comment: you want to verify the email id or want to also check if the email id exist ?

Comment: It depends largely on your hosting solution what the best answer is here, but you can start by looking at PHPMailer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way for php email verification link.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794959/easiest-way-for-php-email-verification-link)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a high level, what you want to do is roughly the following:

- When a user registers, create a secret code that the user can't figure out himself

  - This can be something that is randomly assigned like a random string
  - This can also be something that you can calculate programmatically (but that the user can't) like an MD5 of the user's email address concatenated to a secret string; doing this could save you a database column since you wouldn't have to store it
- Save the secret code and send it to the user in the form of a link in an email
- Set up a listener at that link, and if the codes match, "activate the user"

As for how to do this step-by-step, [tutorials abound](http://www.google.com/search?q=email+verification+tutorial+php).

Answer (score 2):

Create a unique random number, and store it in a table alongside their user ID.  Email them a message with a link to a page that accepts the random number as input.  If they have the correct random number, then mark their account active.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP 5.2 or greater, one option is the filter_var function...

```
if (filter_var('email@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== FALSE)
```

Comment: Although the crappy part about FILTER_VAL

Comment: I don't think he wants to just validate the format of the email.  He wants to validate that the email is a real email address that belongs to the user.  So, he wants to send a confirmation email with a link that the user must click on.  If the user enters a bogus email, he cannot validate his account and log in.

Answer (score 1):

Going to go with the following approach.

User registers.
Database is updated with their details and a flag added for active/not active.
Email is sent to registered email address with link.
Link goes to a page that can confirm the email address as valid and update the database.

No idea what environment your working in and making a few assumptions, this is roughly how you go about it.

I assume you are already persisting the user registration?
You for the following will want to generate a hash of some kind and insert this along with the user/member details...

```
$hash = substr(md5(uniqid()), 0, 5);
```

Do you feel confident in constructing an email view and sending it with phpMailer or similar?
If so, do so, with a link that when its hit, will grab the member_id and the member_hash and so something like the following...
I used PDO here, again, so many ways to do what you want... whatever is best for you.

```
// PDO Instance
$pdo = $this->actionServer->getDataSource('PDO');

$findMember = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM member WHERE member.member_id = :memberId AND member.member_hash = :memberHash AND hidden = 1');
$findMember->bindParam(':memberId', $memberId);
$findMember->bindParam(':memberHash', $memberHash);
$findMember->execute();
$findMemberResult = $findMember->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (empty($findMemberResult)) {
    $this->log->error('Could not find member based on ID and Hash combination');
    throw new HTTPException(404);
}

/**
 * Could use a method like below to approve
 */

protected function approveMember($memberId, $pdo) {
    $sql = 'UPDATE member SET member.hidden = 0 WHERE member.member_id = :memberId';
    $updateMember = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $updateMember->bindParam(':memberId', $memberId);
    $updateMember->execute();
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Cheerio

Answer (score -2):

I did something similar at one point in time, however I didn't have to validate that the user existed, I did need to validate the formatting and whether it was a real domain or not (scrub none@none.com). You can look at my functions and start there.

```
//Verify formatting
function verify_email($email){

    if(!preg_match('/^[_A-z0-9-]+((\.|\+)[_A-z0-9-]+)*@[A-z0-9-]+(\.[A-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-z]{2,4})$/',$email)){
        return false;
    } else {
        return $email;
    }
}

//Verify MX records exist
function verify_email_dns($email){

    // This will split the email into its front
    // and back (the domain) portions
    list($name, $domain) = split('@',$email);

    if(!(checkdnsrr($domain,'MX') || checkdnsrr($domain, 'A'))){

        // No MX record found
        return false;

    } else {

        // MX record found, return email
        return true;

    }
}
```

You may also check this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email)

Comment: Also, the guys at none.com will be unhappy, that's an actual domain (even though people keep using it as if it weren't). Did you mean `example.com`?

Comment: And what I said to @Sourav. At least you included .info and .mobi, but hey, ".travel doesn't exist (2001!), .museum doesn't exist (2001!), .рф doesn't exist (2010), la la la".

Comment: Please **please** don't do this. It's a terrible idea. Accept whatever the user enters as an email address, provided it contains an @ and a period, and validate by **sending them an email**. I'm so sick of over-zealous/broken email address validation.

Comment: @downvoters This solution worked for me in my application, I suggested validating the domain as a place to start. I also provided a link to a similar SO question.