# Which is the standard method of Email Verification

Tags: php, mysql, email-validation

I am currently working on a big project and the client demands that everything need to be perfect and in standard way, especially in the case of security. There is a user registration session and I have to add email verification feature too.

I was doing email verification with the following method in all my projects.

1. On registration, save the data to users table, with `status` (value of status column) as 0 and a generated random `code` to a column intended for that.
2. Then send a link to the registered mail id with the random `code` ans user's `id` as get variables. 
   Ex: http://site_address.com/verification_url.php?id=1&code=abc123xyz
3. On verification page, this value of get variable (`$_GET['code']`) is compared with the random code saved in database for that user with passed id (`$_GET['id']`)
4. If both the codes are same, `status` will be `set to 1` and displays a    successfully verifies message.

Please let me know whether there is a universally accepted methods for email verification (with guaranteed security). Also I would like to know the security limitations or issues of my method so that I can fix those.

Comment: Verification emails are fine, but include a `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` call, to avoid sending out verification messages to invalid email addresses, and use a Captcha of sorts. BTW: read the help of this site: this question is not a good fit

Comment: You dont need to pass the user id unless your code can be guessed.  Just match the code and check if it exists and its not expired. if yes, mark it verified.

Comment: @ELias Va: Sorry, I don't know any other place where I can ask for help on this matter. Also captcha and email validations are already present.

Comment: @shiplu: Thank you. Will do it. :)

Comment: And don't forget to clear the `verification code` field when a user successfully verified their EMAIL.

Comment: @Jitendra: Thank you. Will do it too. :)

Comment: @AeJey: You already posted a [meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258006/why-my-question-getting-close-votes) about this, no need to drag this out in the comments here.

Comment: The universally accepted method of email verification: [a] if this is a public site, don't validate yourself - instead use oauth (like SO) and have them share an existing, verified email address [b] send an email which is what you are doing, and then make sure there is a time limit on the link [c] do you really need "accounts" on your site? If its an e-commerce service, people will allow guest access.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794959/easiest-way-for-php-email-verification-link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't send the user id, otherwise your method works fine. Sending the user id you tell the outside world abit to much of your database/code design. 
Create strong hashes as code and a expiredate and you will be fine.

Comment: Thank you mate. Will follow your instructions too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please look on below, it may be help with you

- create the activation link like

  ```
  http://www.hostname.com/verification_url.php?id=base64_encode($id)&code=base64_encode($code)
  ```
- verification script

  ```
  <?php

  if(isset($_GET['id'])&&isset($_GET['code'])){
    $id = base64_decode($id);
    # your database connection code here
    # get email id using $id for mailing purpose
    if($id!=NULL){
      # update the user status as active and send success mail
    }
    else{
      # sent failure mail
    }
  }

  ?>
  ```