# Android: Email validation with a link

Tags: android, email, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, verification

When a user register to my app via a email address. How would I send them an 'Activation Link' via email to confirm it is his email address and not a fake one?

I am using Android Studio and a Firebase Database.

I have already looked for an answer but didn't find something about android. Only php or something similar.

[Easiest way for PHP email verification link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794959/easiest-way-for-php-email-verification-link)

[how to verify user clicked on link in email that I sent him/her?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545507/how-to-verify-user-clicked-on-link-in-email-that-i-sent-him-her)

Thanks for help.

Comment: have you done any coding yourself here? firebase will send it out. when they click on it, its confirms it in the db... thats how you know.

Comment: Sorry, but I am new with this topic. Do you have a link for a tutorial? I have found this? Do you mean this? https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/02/email-verification-in-firebase-auth.html